# Constructing a grammar for language of all squared words

Tags: automata, formal-grammar

I need help in constructing a grammar for this language: $L = \{ \alpha \in \{a\}^* \mid \alpha = a^{n^2}, n \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$

All I can tell about $L$ is that it should be at least context-free.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a fairly obvious consequence of the [pumping lemma for context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) that this language is *not* context-free.

Comment: Actually, every context-free language on a one-letter alphabet is regular, which is certainly not the case for $L$.